# recreate auto increment php in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i've been looking a while if somebody had a similar question, and there are a few, but not with the solution i need. their increments work perfectly fine but when they have a some rows like this

id
1   hello
2   hello
3   hello
4   hello

but when they delete row 3, row 4 becomes 3. I want it just like php where 4 stays 4 and doesn't become 3 so the next time you would add a row it would look like

id
1 hello
2 hello
4 hello
5 hello

see the following code for yourself; I can't figure it out

```
      <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>titel</th>
            <th>beschrijving</th>
            <th>deadline</th>
            <th>delete task</th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>  

    <div class="forms flex flex-around">
        <form >
        <h2>Add Tasks</h2> 
        titel: <input type="text" name="titel" id="send"><br />
        beschrijving: <input type="text"  id="send"  name="beschrijving"><br />
        deadline: <input type="date"  id="send" name="deadline"><br />
        <!-- <input type="submit" value="Add" name="type" class="center" onclick="myFunction()"> -->
        <button type="button" value="Add" id="handler" class="center button-add" onclick="addRow(); ">add task</button>
        </form>          
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  buildTable();
});

function buildTable() {
  const retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("table");
  const parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);

  for (i = 0; i < parsedObject.length; i++) {
    addRow(parsedObject[i])
  }
}

function addRow(rowData = false) {

  var table = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

  if (!rowData) {
    cell2.innerHTML = '<td><a href="detail.html">' + document.querySelector('[name="titel"]').value; + '</a></td>';
    cell3.innerHTML = document.querySelector('[name="beschrijving"]').value;
    cell4.innerHTML = document.querySelector('[name="deadline"]').value;
  } else {
    cell2.innerHTML = '<td><a href="detail.html">' + rowData.title + '</a></td>';
    cell3.innerHTML = rowData.description;
    cell4.innerHTML = rowData.deadline;
  }

  cell5.innerHTML = '<button class="button-add last-row"  type="button" onClick="deleteRow()" >' +
    'delete</button>';

  getAndSaveTableValues();
}

function getTblValues(tableName = false) {

  if (!tableName) {
    console.log('Please enter a tableName, function won\'t work without it');
    return;
  }

  const dataArray = new Array();

  $(`${tableName} tbody tr`).each(function(rowIndex, tr) {

    dataArray[rowIndex] = {
      "id": rowIndex,
      "title": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
      "description": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
      "deadline": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
    }
  });

  return dataArray;
}

function deleteRow() {
  var td = event.target.parentNode;
  var tr = td.parentNode;
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  getAndSaveTableValues();
};
```

as you can see I have pretty much everything set, but because my  messyness and few months of coding I completely lost track and don't know how to fix the increment I've tried many things but ended up breaking it fully,

Any help is welcome not only the solution but if you see something that could be smarter coded let me know

Comment: when  i replace table.rows.length with a global counter and i add 5 rows, the moment i delete a row and want to add a row after that is gives: The provided index (6 is outside the range [-1, 4].

Comment: Apologies - change `table.insertRow(table.rows.length)` to `table.insertRow(-1)` to put it at the end. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow

Comment: no worries, you are a hero for solving that it works. but the moment i refresh(retrieve localstorage all my id become 0, any idea how this happens. this stands apart from your code ofc haha not that i blame your code for let his happen

Comment: I can't see anywhere else that you're using the row index for this statement "*I need their increments [to] work perfectly"* - as in you're not creating "row 5" your just creating "new row" so just add one to the bottom, in jquery it would be `$("#myTable>tbody").append("tr")`

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully know how to fix this problem, but have you tried to replace the value with `null` instaed of `.removeChild(tr)`?